# Show a filtered timeline/project summary

Tags: task-list, timeline

I am coordinating a project that has an overall timeline and four sub-groups.

I have created a page for each of these groups. Each page includes a document web app where the default view is set to show only documents tagged as related to that group.

I'd like to do something similar for the project timeline. I have an overall timeline that I am showing on the main page, and then for each sub-group, I would like to show a timeline/summary of only tasks and events that are relevant to them.

I know there is no filter option for the project timeline web part without editing the XML. Is there a way to create distinct sub-lists for each of these groups, that will still feed into the main timeline?

I found this guide about using JS to do this, but I am unfamiliar and unsure which parts of the script need replacing with actual unique content relevant to my site.

http://www.ozkary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-adding-multiple.html

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Did everything above but still show Tasks that are tagged as for another department. My timeline is only supposed to show Engineering tasks on the Engineering Page, Contracts Tasks on the Contract page timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a filter option for the project timeline web part. If you don't already have a custom column for these sub-groups, you should create them. Consider the following implementation:

Create a new view for your Project Timeline for each sub-group

- Go to *Site Contents* > *Settings* of your *Task-list* (by default named as "Tasks")
- At the bottom of the *Settings*, click *Create view*
- You can use an existing view such as *My Tasks* as the base
- Name it by e.g. your sub-group's name
- on *Filter*-section, choose on "Show the items when column" as *your column determining the sub-group of a task* - *is equal to* - *sub-group's name*

  - Save the view

Finally, for each of your sub-group's page, add the Task list web part and change the view to match the sub-group.

Comment: Thanks moe - however this view filter only seems to affect the task list under the timeline, rather than the timeline itself. On the timeline for team A, I still see all tasks, rather than just those for team A.

Answer (score 1):

On the Page:
Click on Page, click Edit
Then select Timeline
Then from the far right corner of timeline drop down menu you should be able to edit and select the specific view to be displayed.